# ¿Cómo asignar una formula a una celda de un archivo Excel generado desde VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, excel

Como puedo crear una formula desde un archivo `excel` que estoy generando con `visual basic`. Por ejemplo que e1,e2,e3 sea el resultado c1,c2,c3 se multipliquen por d30 respectivamente

Comment: Removida etiqueta Visual Studio 2015 debido a que no tiene nada que ver con el IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si he entendido correctamente la pregunta que querías formular. Entiendo que quieres crear fórmulas en las celdas e1, e2 y e3 que tomen el valor de c1, c2 y c3 respectivamente y lo multipliquen por d30.

```
        eHoja.Cells(1, 5).Value = "=C1*D30"
        eHoja.Cells(2, 5).Value = "=C2*D30"
        eHoja.Cells(3, 5).Value = "=C3*D30"
```